# IBM DevOps ActiveDeploy Begin Job fails when cloning the common Git repository

Tags: ibm-cloud, active-deploy

I had successfully been using ActiveDeploy inside my IBM Bluemix Build&Deploy pipeline for several months.
Last week, it suddenly stopped working.
It now fails during the `ActiveDeploy - Begin` job, with the following error:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
git clone https://github.com/Osthanes/activedeploy_common.git common
Cloning into 'common'...

Finished: FAILED
```

Could someone please provide some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for reporting the issue. I was able to reproduce the issue but I don't have a solution as of now. When exactly did you detected the issue last week?

Comment: The issue was fixed now. Please try again.

Comment: Seems like the issue I had is fixed indeed. Thanks.
However, I now have a new issue:

*--- ERROR: Invalid rampup duration '30s' detected*.

This used to work before

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue and fixed it right now. Please try again.

Comment: Everything seems to be working as it was before. Thanks a lot :-)